# Thinking Sphinx error on searching "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Thinking Sphinx gives a error on searching some special chars like  `/`, `)` etc.
I thought adding them to the `charset_table` configuration in `sphinx.yml` would solve the problem, but it didn't.

What I did was:

```
charset_table: "0..9, a..z, _, @, A..Z->a..z, /"
```

I even tried adding `U+002F` to the charset table, but it also didn't work.

So what's the best possible solution for this?

1. Something like the above, although it didn't work for me? May be I am wrong somewhere?
2. Escaping the "search term" before querying Sphinx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run in to this same issue. Try escaping the string you are querying against using `Riddle.escape`.

So a search might be:

```
Post.search(Riddle.escape("$foo@bar/something") # no idea why you would search for that
```

Comment: So you mean the best option is `escaping` the query string ?. And i wonder, why Sphinx wont handle it itself (being a very popular search engine). Also were you successful with adding character into `charset_table` configuration ?

Comment: @Ramandeep Singh /, ) are special chars in syntax construction, this is why you need to escape them,even if you added them in charset.